I got `usecols` to select a subset and avoid this error problem
I load a .txt file into variable and reshape it, However, I got ValueError: the number of columns changed from 5 to 4 at row 205; use `usecols` to select a subset and avoid this error, How can I fix it?
My Code
from numpy import loadtxt
data = np.loadtxt('dense128.txt')
data_2d = data.reshape(128, 1024)

My data
-0.04437835    0.2683646    -0.04066011   -0.05485807    0.07532401
  -0.051052462   0.007219632  -0.014079349  -0.04061449   -0.008055394
   0.07079242    0.031491395  -0.058560893   0.005037322   0.025653442
   0.09527966    0.029884877  -0.0044821487  0.08880435    0.10437595
   .....
  -0.07650192   -0.05914555   -0.034037612  -0.2246162     0.19326839
  -0.3463315    -0.26035556    0.04528108   -0.19029921   -0.102362975
   0.21399875    0.000607502  -0.25709382    0.07336428  


With the information provided, I would presume your input data is "corrupted". That is, not all rows in your CSV file have the same number of columns.
You can easily confirm my suspicion by checking how many rows there are in your data file. If there are 205 rows, then the error is referring to the last row of your data. In the excerpt you've given of your data, I can see the last (and thus presumably the 205th) row of your data has only 4 values, whereas the others have 5.
You can avoid this error by either omitting that last row of data, or provide a 5th value of that 205th row (either a forgotten data point, or a missing value of some sort).
